The solution operator of a linear problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is positive?
For a given $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, by Riesz Representation Theorem there exists a unique $u_f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that weak solution of
$$
-\Delta u + u = f, \quad \mathbb{R}^N,
$$
that is
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u_f \nabla \varphi + u_f \varphi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f \varphi, \quad \forall \varphi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N).
$$
If we assume $f \geq 0$, is it true that $u_f \geq 0$, like in the bounded domain case? If this is no the case, what about if we assume $f \in W^{2,p}_{\textrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for large $p$ ?
Another question is: Is it true that $u_{f^+} = 0$ in $\{ f < 0\}$ ?

The proof from the bounded domain case works here as well: set $\phi := \min (u_f,0)$ in your equation.

Can you clarify what is $u_{f^+}$ ?

It is the weak solution of the linear problem with $f^+$.

Let $\eta_1(x)$ be the standard mollifier supported on $B_1\subset\mathbb{R}^N$, define $\eta_{\varepsilon}(x) = \varepsilon^{-N}\eta(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})$. Assume that $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is a weak solution to
$$
  -\Delta u + u = f,\quad \text{in}\ \ \mathbb{R}^N\qquad (1).
$$
Set $u_{\varepsilon}(x) = u*\eta_{\varepsilon}(x)$ and $f_{\varepsilon}(x) = f*\eta_{\varepsilon}(x)$. Since $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N), u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, we have $f_{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^N), u_{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Then $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}u_{\varepsilon}=0$.
It is easy to check that
$$
  -\Delta u_{\varepsilon} + u_{\varepsilon} = f_{\varepsilon},\quad \text{in}\ \ \mathbb{R}^N\qquad (2).
$$
Since $f\ge0$, one gets $f_{\varepsilon}\ge0$. Then applying strong maximum principle into $(2)$, we have $u_{\varepsilon}\ge0$. By the definition of $u_{\varepsilon}$, one gets
$$
  \left\|u_{\varepsilon}-u\right\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)}\to 0,\qquad as\ \ \varepsilon\to 0^+.
$$
Then $u\ge0,\ \text{a.e.}\ \text{in}\ \mathbb{R}^N$. As for the "another question", the answer is   also positive by strong maximum principle for $f\in W_{\text{loc}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^N),\ p>N/2$.

Thank you Guyang Huan for the very nice and neat answer. If I consider $f^+$ in yout item (1), I get the weak solution $u_{f^{+}}$. How can I use the strong maximum principle in order to see that $u_{f^{+}}(x) = 0$ for all $x \in {x : f(x) < 0}$? Can I use the mollifier idea to get it ?
